# Precision timing using arduino and external clock

Tags: arduino, frequency, clock, bootloader

I'm working on a very time limited project (8 weeks). Basically I need to perform measurements and save to memory. 
2 identical boxes, 4 hours and no wireless or wired connection. 
Each box is measuring on accelerometers.

Due to the limitation in time I need a platform with minimal soldering, PSU design and so forth.

The Arduino is an obvious choice but the crystal is simply to unstable. I need precision of +/- 30 ppb of clock frequency.

I've found OCXO that meet spec but not at 16Mhz..(or 8)..
Changing the clock speed to 12 MHz would help me a lot - but then the libraries becomes an issue.

My idea so far is to use arduino, write a program that sets a digital pin **high**, then waits x microseconds and then sets digital pin **low**. This way I can calibrate the x using a oscilloscope to land the right frequency of sampling.. hmm

Ideas?

Comment: I hope you realize that 30 ppb  is the accuracy of a clock with an error of less than 1 second every 951 years ! 30 ppm sounds more reasonable but is still 1 second per year. Do you need 30 ppb/ppm **stability** or **absolute accuracy** ? The last one will be almost impossible without specialized equipment.

Comment: Looks like something similar to the Hafele-Keating experiment ? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment  Now you know why they used atomic clocks.

Comment: @FakeMoustache 
Maybe my calculations are wrong but I would say that: 
4 hours = 14400 seconds * (5 *10^-9) = 72 us (microseconds)

Here 5 is the error of 5 ppb of the crystal

Comment: To answer your question: 
I need to isolated sampling systems that cannot communicate. So they are initiated and then isolated for 4 hours. Then I'll retrieve the data and need it to be within 1 sample of difference. Sampling is done at 1 kHz on both systems.

Comment: 72 us on 4 hours is indeed 5 ppb. But this is the **ratio** between the timings, not the accuracy. To explain: if you had an (not so stable) clock of 1 MHz so 1 us pulses. You could make a counter, count 14.4E9 pulses (that is 4 hours), start the pulse, count 72 pulses, end the pulse.

Comment: OK, so the clocks need to deviate less than 1 ms (1 / 1k Hz) from each other over 4 hours. That's still about 70 ppb. But you do not need 70 ppb accurate clocks/crystals. What you need is **stable** clocks which you can syncronize/calibrate. You could compensate for the timing difference in software. For example one clock runs 0.01% faster than the other. Then instead of waiting 14400 seconds it must wait less (as it has "shorter" seconds) so you make it wait 14400 - 0.01% = 14398.56 seconds.

Comment: You are right, but! During the 4 hours, I cannot predict the temperature development. Box 1 could potentially be at -40 and box 2 at + 80. 
They could drift in opposite directions.

How would I go about syncronize/calibrating that?

Comment: Yes that is true, the "unsynchronised" drift / temperatures will be a problem. So when selecting a clock/crystal, pay attention to the drift. Low drift crystal oscillators are made by placing the crystal in an "oven" meaning an isolated box with a heating element to keep the crystal at a constant temperature of like 60 degrees C.

Comment: Something like this right? 
http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1912976.pdf

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. This might just be good enough for your needs. There probably are even "better" ones but these might be very costly.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion! 
I think we are on the same track now.

Comment: My pleasure :-) Good luck with this challenging project !

Comment: "Then I'll retrieve the data and need it to be within 1 sample of difference." - Are you sure that's a hard requirement? Can't you compensate for any regular differences when post-processing the data?

Comment: @FakeMoustache - according to my arithmetic, there are 31,536,000 seconds in a (365 day) year. So 30ppm error could be as bad as 946 seconds/year (32.556 * 30), and *not* 1 second/year as your comment suggested. 30ppb is only 1,000 times better, and hence is slightly better than 1 second/year, and *not* 1 second every 951 years. I thought I should mention it.

Comment: FYI -- very few physical things can be measured to 30 ppb of accuracy without extraordinary sophistication -- time can, maybe length or voltage. Even gravity (accelerometer) varies by 10's of PPM from location to location. 
Measuring pulses with an oscilloscope won't be so accurate either -- they don't have temperature stabilized clocks, and measuring rising-to-falling edges adds prop delay and slew time errors.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an Arduino, but calibrate it to an external clock (or replace the clock with the external one).

For instance Teensy 3.0 can use this FreqCount library https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_FreqCount.html and basically compare its internal clock with an external one -- for 30 ppb, you'll need to average over 1 minute or so, but you can then calibrate your internal oscillator for basic timing.

To keep things stable you'll need to ensure the temperature of the arduino's crystal doesn't change too quickly for the calibration to catch up.

Alternatively, use an arduino, and replace its crystal with an external OCXO signal.

Comment: Interesting library - I'll give it a look. 

Replacing the crystal with an OCXO is my current plan, but I haven't found OCXO that are precise enough and has a freq. of 16 Mhz. What are the implications of changing the clockfreq. ? 
I've read that e.g. millis() are affected since the arduino library does a divison of 16/16mhz = 1 us...

Comment: The Teensy expects a 16 MHz at boot up, but with some effort, you may be able to switch later. Instead, use the Teensy & FrequencyCount lib to count an external OCXO (10 MHz), and calibrate all other readings/settings to that.